# How to prevent the mouseover of parent element when the cursor leaves child element to hover parent element?

Tags: javascript, html, parent-child, dom-events, onmouseover

I have a parent div and a child div inside, as follow :

```html
<div id="parent" onmouseover="console.log('foo');" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:blue;">
 
 <div id="child" style="width:50px;height:50px;background-color:red;">
 </div>

</div>
```

As you can see, in the parent div, I just add `onmouseover="console.log('foo');"`.

So when I hover the div parent from outside or when I hover child div, the console displays "foo", no problem.

But when I hover the parent div from child div, that is say, when the cursor leaves child div to hover parent div, the console displays "foo", it's a problem, because I want to prevent it, I don't want execute an event handler.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to using the `mouseenter` event.

```html
<div id="parent" onmouseenter="console.log('foo');" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:blue;">
 
 <div id="child" style="width:50px;height:50px;background-color:red;">
 </div>

</div>
```